# Do VLANs within a subnet need to have their own subnet for router on a stick?

Tags: router, vlan, subnet, trunk, gateway

I have been creating a network lab in packet tracer for practice. I have 3 vlans in subnet A and I am trying to configure router on a stick at gig6/0 on the bottom left of the image. Do I need to create a subnet for each VLAN in order for the router on a stick gateway to work?
[image: Practice network]

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: what is the Default gateway for the Vlans? the same for everyone or a new one for each?

Answer (score 7):

I'm not understanding your exact problem because you don't provide enough detail but maybe this helps:

With rare exceptions, an IP subnet is mapped to a VLAN = broadcast domain = layer-2 network on a 1:1 basis.

You can run multiple IP subnets inside a single VLAN but they need a router to communicate with each other. Most often this setup doesn't make too much sense.

You can't run a single IP subnet across multiple VLANs though (without elaborate workarounds). Nodes in the same subnet expect to be able to talk to each other on a common layer-2 network = VLAN = broadcast domain.

So, your "VLANs within a subnet" can only work when you've split that subnet into sub-subnets properly and set up the router as gateway in between. A router on a stick is a router forwarding between VLAN subinterfaces on a single physical interface. Each subinterface needs to connect to one of the desired VLANs, so the link needs to be a VLAN trunk on both the switch and the router side.

Answer (score 6):

Just to amplify on Zac’s answer: you have one subnet per vlan and vice versa. At the CCNA level, you can ignore the rare exceptions. The router on a stick has an (sub)interface in each subnet.   Therefore all VLANs must be trunked to the router.

Answer (score 0):

In practice, it is always a good idea to have VLAN with its own subnet. However, you can split a subnet into multiple VLANs since it is only a test topology and you don't have to worry about the IP address management challenges.

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking about it backwards. It is not:

> I have 3 vlans in subnet A

Rather, for example, think about it as:

> I have 3 subnets in VLAN 1.

Remember VLAN's are to be thought of as physical switches or bridges, basically a broadcast domain, or a shared Layer 2 network. VLAN's are a way to carve out particular physical switchports to include a particular local area network, or LAN, or virtual LAN (VLAN).

Remember that you technically can have several subnets operating over a single switch, or bridge, or LAN, or VLAN. IP operates at a higher level than Layer 2.

A router on a stick simply refers to the physical implementation of a router having a single link into the LAN.